# SQLSTATE[HY093] in PHP Query and Answer cannot be found

Tags: php, sql, pdo, parameters

I have been working on a website for a while that you can edit using an api and a Windows application, I have finished all that code so I added a registration system with working tokens (hash's).

I went and created them and so I got so far as creating the login system registration and login, it worked so I decided to add the token system into the code, I tested the token system it works but the normal untouched code then started to fail (it is the same as before I added the token system), I have searched the code and cannot find the problem, here is the whole PHP script I have been using:

```
<?php
require("common.php");
require("code.php");

//die("Registration is currently disabled");

if (!empty($_GET['token'])) {
$token = $_GET['token'];

if (getRegistrationValid($token)) {
    $username = getRegistrationUsername($token);
    $level    = getRegistrationLevel($token);

    // This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is     displayed 
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $username = getRegistrationUsername($token);
        $level    = getRegistrationLevel($token);

        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username 
        if (empty($username)) {
            die("Problem with token. ERR[1]");
        }

        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password 
        if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
            die("Please enter a password. ERR[2]");
        }

        // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address 
        if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            die("Invalid E-Mail Address. ERR[3]");
        }

        $query = " 
               SELECT 
                   1 
               FROM $dbtable 
               WHERE 
                   username = :username 
           ";

        $query_params = array(
            ':username' => $username
        );

        try {
            // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
            $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage() . " ERR[4]");
        }

        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        if ($row) {
            die("This username is already in use ERR[5]");
        }

        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $query = " 
               SELECT 
                   1 
               FROM $dbtable 
               WHERE 
                   email = :email 
           ";

        $query_params = array(
            ':email' => $email
        );

        try {
            $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage() . " ERR[6]");
        }

        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        if ($row) {
            die("This email address is already registered ERR[7]");
        }

        $query = " 
               INSERT INTO $dbtable ( 
                   username, 
                   password, 
                   salt, 
                   email,
                   level
               ) VALUES ( 
                   :username, 
                   :password, 
                   :salt, 
                   :email,
                   :level
               )
           ";

        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));

        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt);

        for ($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) {
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
        }

        if($username == null) { die ("$ level == null"); }
        if($password == null) { die ("$ password == null"); }
        if ($salt == null) { die ("$ salt == null"); }
        if ($email == null) { die ("$ email == null"); }
        if ($level == null) { die ("$ level == null"); }

        $query_params = array(
            ':username' => $username,
            ':password' => $password,
            ':salt' => $salt,
            ':email' => $email,
            ':level:' => $level
        );

        try {
            // Execute the query to create the user 
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage() . " ERR[8] <br>" . $ex->getTraceAsString() . "<br>" . $ex->getLine() . "<br>" . $ex->getCode());
        }

        // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register 
        header("Location: login.php");

        die("Redirecting to login.php");
    }
} else {
    die("Invalid Token ERR[9]");
}
} else {
die("Invalid Token - No token found in post ERR[10]");
}

function getLevel($tok) {
$levelid = getRegistrationLevel($tok); 

if($levelid == 0) {
    return "Standard user";
} 
if ($levelid == 1) {
    return "Admin";
} 
if ($levelid == 2) {
    return "Webpage Editor";
}

return "Unknown";
}
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-    min.css">
<body style="background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
  <div style="text-align: center;"></div>
<div
 style="border: 10px solid rgb(201, 214, 228); margin: 30px auto 0px; padding: 10px; width: 154px; background-color: rgb(237, 237, 237); font-size: 12px; font-family: Tahoma; color: rgb(129, 129, 129); text-align: left;">
<div style="text-align: center;"></div>
<div
 style="font-size: 30px; font-family: impact; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: center;"><span
 style="font-weight: bold;">Register</span>
 <br>
<strong style="font-family: Gisha;"></strong>
</div>
<br>
  <form action="register.php?token=<?php echo $token; ?>" method="post"> 
  Username: <?php echo $username; ?><br>
    <br>
  Level: <?php echo getLevel($token); ?><br>
    <br>
  E-Mail:<br>
    <input name="email" value="" type="text" style="width:100%"> <br>
    <br>
  Password:<br>
    <input name="password" value="" type="password" style="width:100%">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input value="Register" type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" style="width:100%"> 
    <br>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
```

After I uploaded the script to the web server and tried to run it I got err[10] and I made it output all that I could to help me understand and nothing stall would show me the parm that is causing the error, the output is

```
Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter         was not defined ERR[8] 
#0 /home/webcontroller/public_html/admin/manage/register.php(180): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main}
180
HY093
```

Here is what should of happened to those who could not figure it out or wants to know,

```
[Pseudo Code]
  1. User gets mailed or sent link to ..../admin/register.php?token=blah (or slam head here - qwesdnloweadkfnjln)
  2. The form will load showing the designated username
  3. The user will enter in the details required
  4. User clicks submit then redirect with post request
  5. Check the email, if email is used - inform user and die to stop registration
  6. Encrypt the password
  7. Create SQL Query (To insert information into DB)
  8. Create SQL Query Params (anti SQL Injection)
  9. Run Query -> insert information
  10. Redirect to login page for user to continue their advert to whatever awaits them.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra colon in one of your parameter array keys:

```
$query_params = array(
        ':username' => $username,
        ':password' => $password,
        ':salt' => $salt,
        ':email' => $email,
        ':level:' => $level  // this should just be ':level'
    );
```

As a side note - if you individually bind the parameters instead of passing as a whole array, you should get a more discriminating error message:

```
$query = "....";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":username", $username);

...

$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i would of never noticed that, thanks. Also thanks on the tip of binding single params!